# Getting empty data from USB communication on my Android Device

Tags: android, usb, communication

I'm developing Android application which should communicate with my hardware via USB. I've established connection, but all recieved data seem to be empty, but in correct length (there should be no problem with output from my hardware, tested via WiFi, BT,COM and everything working well). Do someone see any problem in my code listed below?

```
 try {
                UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) BoardActivity.ctx.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

                UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
                UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);

                UsbDeviceConnection connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);

                connection.claimInterface(intf, true);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
                //UsbRequest usbRequest = new UsbRequest();
                //usbRequest.initialize(connection, endpoint);
                //ByteBuffer bytesBuff = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
                while (true) {
                    //usbRequest.queue(bytesBuff, bytes.length);
                    //connection.requestWait();
                    int len = connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, bytes, bytes.length, 0);
                    //Log.d("USB_TEST", Util.bytesToHex(bytes, bytes.length));
                    Log.d("USB_TEST", Util.bytesToHex(bytes, len));
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            ;
```

I also tried library FTDriver (https://github.com/ksksue/FTDriver) from GitHub, but with same result, connection is established correctly, data flows in expected period and length but every values in bytebuffer are zeros.

```
FTDriver mUSBSerial = new FTDriver((UsbManager) BoardActivity.ctx.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));
mUSBSerial.usbAttached(intent);
boolean connOk = mUSBSerial.begin(FTDriver.BAUD115200);
Log.i(TAG_USB, "Connestion result " + connOk);
```

Answer (score 0):

Communication via USB is not so simple, and without detail it is hard to say exactly where the problem is (I do not have your hardware). However, here I give part of the code (it is c#+xamarin) for the inspiration what all do you need to solve.

In short: You need to find USBDevice obtain a permit, set ControlTransfer (have correctly RequestType and BaudRate for your hardware), start communicating and using temp buffer for fast read and processed data later and a lot of debugging and testing.

In Res.xml.device_filter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
      <!-- POZOR, aby proslo buildem, musim v properties tohoto souboru nastavit BuildAction na AndroidResource  -->
      <!--<usb-device vendor-id="0403" product-id="6001" /> FTDI FT232R UART in hexa-->
      <usb-device vendor-id="1027" product-id="24577" />
      <!--FTDI FT232R UART in decimal-->
    </resources>
```

Code

```
private UsbManager USBManager = null;
private UsbDevice USBDevice = null;
private UsbDeviceConnection USBConnection = null;
private UsbEndpoint USBEndPointRead = null;
private UsbEndpoint USBEndPointWrite = null;

private Object InternalBufferReadLock = new Object();
private Object TempBufferReadLock = new Object();
private Object BufferReadLock = new Object();
private Object WriteBufferLock = new Object();

private byte[] InternalBufferRead = new byte[UsbPacketSize];
private byte[] TempBufferRead = new byte[UsbPacketSize];
private byte[] BufferRead = new byte[UsbBufferSize];//This buffer used cursor  BufferReadWriteCursor/BufferReadReadCursor
private int BufferReadWriteCursor = 0;
private int BufferReadReadCursor = 0;

private const int UsbBaudRate = 26;// baudrate  speed-hexa-int9600-0x4138-16696, 19200-0x809C-32924, 115200-0x001A-26,  230040-0x000D-13,460800-0x4006-16390,921600-0x8003-32771
private const int UsbPacketSize = 64;
private const int UsbBufferSize = 65536;

private volatile bool ContinueCycle = false;

private void PrepareCommunication(UsbDevice pUsbDevice, bool pFromActivity)
{
  Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 1, "pUsbDevice=" + pUsbDevice + ", pFromActivity=" + pFromActivity);
  if (USBManager == null)
  {
    object obj = this.GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
    if (obj != null && obj is UsbManager)
    {
      USBManager = (UsbManager)obj;
      Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBManager OK");
    }
    else Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBManager NOT FINDED");
  }
  if (USBManager != null)
  {
    if (pUsbDevice != null)
    {//If I get it from BroadcastReceiver intent android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED
      Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBDevice from broadcast ATTACHED USB");
      USBDevice = pUsbDevice;
    }
    if (USBDevice == null)
    {//If I have not I'll find
       Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBDevice is null, try find someone");
      if (USBManager.DeviceList != null && USBManager.DeviceList.Count > 0 && USBManager.DeviceList.Values != null && USBManager.DeviceList.Values.Count > 0)
      {
        Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBDevice DeviceList contains something");
        ICollection<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = (ICollection<UsbDevice>)USBManager.DeviceList.Values;
        if (deviceIterator.Count > 1) Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBDevice DeviceList.Values.Count=" + USBManager.DeviceList.Values.Count);
        foreach (UsbDevice tmpUsbDevice in deviceIterator)
        {
          USBDevice = tmpUsbDevice;//Beru pouze prvni.
          Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBDevice FINDED from deviceIterator");
          break;
        }
      }
      else Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBDevice NOTHING in DeviceList");
    }
    if (USBDevice != null)
    {
      if (!USBManager.HasPermission(USBDevice))
      {
        Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBDevice HAS NOT PERMISSION YET send request permission");
        PendingIntent permissionIntent;
        permissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(ApplicationContext, 0, new Intent("EVOAndroidUSBService.EVOAndroidUSBService.UsbServiceUnit.USB_PERMISSION"), 0);
        USBManager.RequestPermission(USBDevice, permissionIntent);//User confirm permission and the broadcast delivered the intent and than must re-run this method. Then he will have permission
      }
      else
      {
        Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBDevice HAS PERMISSION YET");
        if (USBConnection == null)
        {
          Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBConnection is null, try create by OpenDevice");
          USBConnection = USBManager.OpenDevice(USBDevice);
        }
        if (USBConnection != null)
        {//It is an open connection, so I find the interface and EndPoint ...
          UsbInterface usbInterface = USBDevice.GetInterface(0);
          if (usbInterface != null)
          {
            UsbEndpoint usbEndpoint1 = usbInterface.GetEndpoint(0);
            UsbEndpoint usbEndpoint2 = usbInterface.GetEndpoint(1);
            if (usbEndpoint1 != null && usbEndpoint1.Direction == UsbAddressing.In)
            {//input endpoint                                    
              USBConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// reset  mConnection.controlTransfer(0×40, 0, 1, 0, null, 0, 0);//clear Rx
              USBConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 0, 1, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Rx
              USBConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 0, 2, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Tx
              USBConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 3, UsbBaudRate, 0, null, 0, 0);// baudrate  speed-hexa-int 115200-0x001A-26, 9600-0x4138-16696, 19200-0x809C-32924, 230040-0x000D-13
              USBConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 2, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// flow  control none                                                            
              USBConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 4, 8, 0, null, 0, 0);// data bit  8, parity  none,  stop bit 1, tx off

              USBEndPointRead = usbEndpoint1;//Zkusim prvne bez spozdeni rovnou.                      
            }
            if (usbEndpoint2 != null && usbEndpoint2.Direction == UsbAddressing.Out)
            {//output endpoint
              USBEndPointWrite = usbEndpoint2;
            }
          }
          else Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "usbInterface IS NULL");
        }
        else Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBConnection IS STILL NULL");
      }
    }
    else Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBDevice IS STILL NULL");
  }
  else Utils.MyLog("USB", "PrepareCommunication", 0, "USBManager IS STILL NULL");

  if (USBEndPointRead != null && USBConnection != null && USBDevice != null)
  {//StartCommunication in other thread
    if (!ContinueCycle) ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => StartCommunication());
  }
}

private void StartCommunication()
{
  ContinueCycle = true;
  while (ContinueCycle)
  {
    if (USBEndPointRead != null && USBConnection != null)
    {
      int rxlen;
      lock (InternalBufferReadLock)
      {//only quickly read and save to TempBufferRead
        rxlen = USBConnection.BulkTransfer(USBEndPointRead, InternalBufferRead, InternalBufferRead.Length, 0);
        Array.Copy(InternalBufferRead, TempBufferRead, rxlen);
      }
      if (rxlen > 2)//FTDI chip keeps sending 2 status byte, regardless of whether or not the data (if the data is the same as at the beginning of status byte ...) with an interval of approx. 16ms
      {//if it is more than 2 bytes than the data exists
        lock (BufferReadLock)
        {//Put data into MainBuffer                      
          for (int i = 2; i < rxlen; i++)
          {
            BufferRead[BufferReadWriteCursor] = TempBufferRead[i];//and then once a while (eg. the timer) you read data from MainBufferu and process .
            BufferReadWriteCursor++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```